# Power BI - Understanding Filters in Drill Through from Table

Tags: powerbi, drillthrough

I am trying to build my first drill through report in Power BI.

My tables look like this :

[image]

The data model looks like this:

[image]

The table in the first report looks like this:

[image]

This report has slicers and text filters that filter on "Region", "Product Description" and "Number of Products".

Upon filtering using slicers, now I am clicking on a row in a table to drill though and opening another report - sub-product report.

When I create a card in the sub-product report for "Region", I get options like, "First", "Last", "Count" etc. First and Last of which set of rows is what I am trying to understand.

The combination of "Region" and "Product Name" given by the column REGION_PNAME is unique. When I filter using the slicers, say it results in 10 rows in the first product report. But I am however drilling through on one row only. Is the drill through solely based on the value of "PNAME" (Product Name) or other values of the row are taken into account ? Because it is possible that a particular product, say P1 can belong to both Region "A" and Region "B" and choosing FIRST_REGION would be incorrect. I want to be able to see just 1 Region Value which belongs to Region - Product combination row on which I drilled through.

I am trying to understand what flows into the second report from the first report when I drill though. I am keeping the filters across reports. In my second report the drill though is "PNAME" (Product Name).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: "First and Last of which set of rows is what I am trying to understand." Are you able to explain about how, at the first place you get stuck as you proceed in some very clear use case, you can't understand the authoritative documentation for a step or can't apply that authoritative documentation to your case, quoting as appropriate?